# Firebase crashlytics is not enable in production mode in flutter iOS application

Tags: flutter, dart

Firebase account I could not get crash in iOS production app. I have added 2 build variant in application. Beside firebase console production iOS application is detected but crash is not showing.
I have uploaded dsyms File using terminal. If any one know about this issue then please help me.
[image]

I have uploaded dsyms File using terminal.

Comment: Can you please share the code of how you added crashlytics and how you are creating a crash

Comment: await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "appname",
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  //FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();



IOS Xcode Configuration

Run script
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

Answer (score 0):

Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?renable-debug-logging&platform=ios

Basically, you need to:

1. In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme.
2. Select Run from the left menu, then select the Arguments
3. In the Arguments Passed on Launch section, add -FIRDebugEnabled.
   Then force a test crash.